# Ayuda! problemas con apache2/php5/PostgeSQL en Debian 6

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, apache2, php5

Desde hace tiempo he tratado de resolver este problema, y poco a poco pierdo las esperanzas y entro en desesperación, ACLARO! NO soy un usuario asiduo de Linux ni ninguna de sus distribuciones (ni quiero) solo es trabajo, cualquier respuesta por favor si es bien explicada y con paciencia lo agradeceré mucho.

ya he instalado php 5.3, Apache 2.2 y PostgreSQL 8.4 y todo lo necesario.

El problema es que el navegador solo muestra una pagina en blanco cuando ejecuto un codigo sencillo php, no encuentro errores, incluso aveces muestra solo partes del codigo como texto(en iceweasel).

- El log de errores de apache no muestra nada fatal.
- Ya edite el Display errors de php.ini a On.

No muestra ni el echo.

No se cuanto de esto sea del hecho de que estoy utilizando chromium o iceweasel ya que instalar Firefox o Google chrome en debian se me ha echo simplemente imposible.

¿Algun usuario experimentado en distribuciones de Linux me puede ayudar?

¿En serio se utilizan S.O tan viejos para servidores o este es un caso "especial"?

codigo que se ejecuta check_usu.php

```
<?php

$user = "postgres";
$password = "iapem";
$dbname = "db_sistema_a";
$port = "5432";
$host = "localhost";

$cadenaConexion = "host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password";

$conexion = pg_connect($cadenaConexion);

if(!($conexion)){

die('No pudo conectarse: ' .pg_last_error());

  }


$usuario = $_POST["usr"];//Traemos los datos del formulario
$clave1 =  $_POST["clave"];//Traemos los datos del formulario

$clave2 = md5($clave1);//Encriptamos la clave a md5 

 $query = "select * from usuarios WHERE ced='$usuario' and psswd_per='$clave2'";//Realizamos query

$result = pg_query($conexion, $query) or die("Error en la Consulta SQL");//Procesamos el query

 $numReg= pg_num_rows($result);

echo $numReg . " rows returned";//Me dice si hay alguien en la base de datos

?>
```

mas simple no puede ser... y esto es lo que resulta:

[image: imagen Chromium]

[image: imagen iceweasel]

Comment: Intenta enviar un echo desde la primera linea de archivo, no vaya a ser que te falte instalar libapache2-mod-php5 y php5-pgsql, por otro lado como estás tomando valores de "POST" es necesario que verifiques que están seteados antes de usarlos

Comment: Puede que sea un detalle irrelevante, pero mejor quita la etiqueta de cierre `?>`

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas y ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

hace un tiempo atras me paso algo similar me mostraba parte del echo y siempre al final mostraba el ?> de php 
la solucion estuvo en instalar php en el debian
apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli ( en mi caso)
espero te sirva

pd: no lo deje en los comentarios ya que no tengo 50 de reputacion

Comment: Hey gracias!!!!